# Is this proof of integrability of a random variable correct?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, solution-verification

My textbook on advanced probability states that
$$\forall \epsilon >0 \exists \delta > 0 \forall A \in \mathbb{F}: P(A) < \delta \implies \int_A |X| dP < \epsilon$$
for a random variable $X$ on $(\Omega,\mathbb{F},P)$ such that $E|X| < \infty$.

I am trying to figure out whether the converse holds, that is that when this implication holds than $E|X| < \infty$. I came up with the following proof:

Let $A_i = (|X|)^{-1}(i)$ -- that is $A_i$ contains all $\omega \in \Omega$ s.t. $|X(\omega)| = i$. Let $\epsilon = 1$ (any other value would work) and let $\delta$ be some value that satisfies the formula above (we are assuming it exists). Now consider separately all $A_i$ with $P(A_i) \geq \delta$ and those with $P(A_i) < \delta$. There are finitely many of the first kind, meaning that they contribute a finite amount to $E|X|$. Now we partition all the $A_i$'s of the second kind into $B_j$'s such that each $B_j$ is a union of some number of $A_i$'s such that $\delta/2 \leq P(B_j) < \delta$ for each $j$ except one $j$ for which only $P(B_j) < \delta$. Note that such partition exists. The inequality $P(B_j) < \delta$ can be satisfied easily and then if we consider a partition that satisfies $P(B_j) < \delta$ for all $j$ and the inequality $\delta/2 \leq P(B_j)$ is violated for smallest possible number of $j$'s, it will only be violated for one as otherwise, we could merge two such sets of the partition. Now the number of $B_j$'s is clearly finite as all but one have probability at least $\delta/2$. Each contributes at most $1$ to $E|X|$ and, therefore, the first absolute moment is finite (one could write it out formally as splitting the integral that is $E|X|$ into two parts, estimating each as I described).

Is this idea correct? The thing is that ew have been told that the converse implication does not hold but it seems to me that this proof should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the set $\{\{i\}:i\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is uncountable, so you cannot get some conclusion from there. By example if $X:(0,1)\to (0,1),\, x\mapsto 1/x$ and the probability measure is the Lebesgue measure in $(0,1)$ then you will have that $\Pr [A_i]=0$ for all $i\in[0,1]$, however $\int_0^1 X\,dP =\infty $.

A counterexample is this: let the probability space $[0,1]$ with the probability measure given by $\Pr [A]=1$ if and only if $0\in A$ and zero otherwise. Now let $X(c)=\infty $ if and only if $c=0$ and zero otherwise, then $\int_{0}^1 X \mathop{}\!d P=\infty $ but for every $\epsilon \in(0,\infty )$ we have that $\int_{A}X\mathop{}\!d P<\epsilon $ if and only if $0\notin A$, so choosing $\delta \in(0,1)$ the condition holds.